# Create shared objects in container using STL

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to generate a container with shared objects.
Say, two linked list with a couple of common nodes.

L1 : {*1 2 3* **2** **1**} and L2 : {**2** **1**}

I know if we use the Node* head and add the dynamically created objects as link, that's possible to chain common objects in both linkedlist, but is it possible to create such shared objects directly in the container ?

I was trying something like this:

```
std::forward_list<int> listOne{1,2,3,2,1}; // 2,1 are meant to be shared
std::forward_list<int> listTwo{1};
listTwo.insert_after(listTwo.begin(), 
std::next(listOne.begin(), 3), listOne.end()); // taking 2,1 from listOne
```

But, that would just create another new allocation.

I'm assuming this might be prohibited due to iterator invalidation scenarios etc. producing abnormal behaviour, but I'm not sure. Is it possible any other way ?

Comment: That's not possible. You can't (re)link nodes of a linked list, that's a linked list's business only.

Comment: Perhaps [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is what you are looking for?

Comment: @Evg one DSA question was to find intersecting node in a linked list, node should be common by the address of the node. Like, I said, it can be done using Node* head, but then I had to create a container class manually, just for this operation. Are there any other better ways to do it ?

Comment: @ppadhy I guess the whole point of that question is implementing a linked list yourself.

Comment: Wha about `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>`?

Comment: @Evg No, I'm just trying to solve for a question. I can use STL for most cases, but if I had to code a question like this where two linked lists are intersecting, then I'm hoping to do that someway through the STL itself. It's a standard DSA question right.. so I'm looking if we could do this through STL somehow.

Comment: @ppadhy Standard library containers *own* the objects they store, so no, you cannot share some part of the list. Some shenanigans can be done with `std::set` and `std::map` (and other associative containers), because it exposes parts of its internal structure since C++17, but even that isn't meant for manual pointer rewiring, just for copy-less moving nodes between maps.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thanks for the info. I assumed that might be the case.

Comment: @Galik That seems doable, just worrying about funny iterator invalidations business, if I delete it from one container and accessing other containers etc in a single scope. But, could be possible.

Comment: You don't have to use `std::vector` but it depends on what you are doing with your iterators. The address of the (`int`) objects themselves will remain stable regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `std::shared_ptr` as that will keep its objects alive regardless if another `std::shared_ptr` pointing to the same object is deleted from a different container.

The container type isn't important for that, so you can use `std::vector` for example:

```
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> v1
    {
        std::make_shared<int>(1),
        std::make_shared<int>(2),
        std::make_shared<int>(3),
        std::make_shared<int>(2),
        std::make_shared<int>(1),
    };

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> v2
    {
        v1[3],
        v1[4],
    };

    std::cout << "v1" << '\n';
    for(auto& sp: v1)
        std::cout << *sp << '\n';

    std::cout << "v2" << '\n';
    for(auto& sp: v2)
        std::cout << *sp << '\n';

    v1.pop_back(); // remove from one container but
    v1.pop_back(); // still alive and kicking in the other 
    std::cout << "----" << '\n';

    std::cout << "v1" << '\n';
    for(auto& sp: v1)
        std::cout << *sp << '\n';

    std::cout << "v2" << '\n';
    for(auto& sp: v2)
        std::cout << *sp << '\n';
```

**Output:**

```
v1
1
2
3
2
1
v2
2
1
----
v1
1
2
3
v2
2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of shared pointers for this.

```cpp
std::list<int> listInt {1,2,3,2,1};

std::list<std::shared_ptr<int>> listOne{};
std::list<std::shared_ptr<int>> listTwo{};

size_t counter = 0;
for(int elem : listInt)
{
    auto ptr1 = std::make_shared<int>(elem);
    listOne.push_back(ptr1);
    if(counter < 3)
        listTwo.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(elem));
    else
        listTwo.push_back(ptr1);
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: You could, but you should expand on why you would want to.